# How To create Custom Cart Price rule In magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3.1

I want to create a custom cart price rule with below conditions

**1. If Subtotal Should be greater than xyz amount then abc product will be free.**

I am able to add condition for greater than xyz but not able to add free product with available rules, Can anyone help me to know how We can achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Use percent of product price - 100% to achieve this. It should look like this.

[image]

**Conditions** tab - should have your cart subtotal amount. Conditions tab tells Magento when the rule should be applied.

**Actions** tab - should have your free item. Actions tab tells Magento what should happen when the conditions tab is met.

*Apply* - percent of product price discount

*Discount Amount* - 100

*Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To* - 1 (so if customer add more than 1 of the free item to cart, they will only get 1 free).

---

**UPDATE -** Since you want to add the item *automatically*, you can do this by observer. Here is simple method you can use, but you still need to create the sales rule in the back end so the discount is applied. And the free item and threshold are hard-coded.

**Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
  <observer name="addFreeItem" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddFreeItem"/>
</event>
```

**Vendor\Module\Observer\AddFreeItem.php**

```
public function __construct (
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quoteItem
  ) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->quoteItem = $quoteItem;
  }

/**
 * @param Observer $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer)
 {
   $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item')->getQuote();
   $quoteTotals = $quote->getTotals();
   $subtotalValue = $quoteTotals['subtotal']['value'];
   $freeItemId = 172;
   $threshold = 100;

   if ($subtotalValue < $threshold) {
      $quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
      $quoteRowTotals = [];
     foreach ($quoteItems as $quoteItem) {
        $quoteRowTotals[] = ($quoteItem->getPrice() * $quoteItem->getQty());
      }
      $subtotalValue = array_sum($quoteRowTotals);
   }

   if ($subtotalValue >= $threshold) {
     $freeItem = $this->productRepository->getById($freeItemId);
     if (!$quote->hasProductId($freeItemId) && $freeItem->getIsSalable()) {
       try {
         $freeItemQuote = $this->quoteItem->setProduct($freeItem)->setQty(1);
         $quote->addItem($freeItemQuote);
       } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\Exception $e) {
         throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
           __($e->getMessage())
         );
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @bernieu2, Its Working fine, But  in this scanario I need to add free product manually, I want to product should be added atutomatically once subtotal is grater than xyz

Comment: Ok, now that is a different question. You can create an observer to do this, but it can be tricky and cause headaches. I edit answer with a simple observer, but the threshold and free item id are hard-coded. You would still need to create the cart rule in admin to get the discount. If something goes wrong with observer, it will prevent the actual item customer wants being added to cart.

Comment: Okay. But try with this solution and added custom logs, evrything goes to line bye line but no free product added to cart

Comment: How did you test? I didn't test widely, but it worked. I see now though, if the quote doesn't exist yet - you have nothing in cart, and add a product over the threshold or a quantity of single product that would put you over it won't add in that instance. It will only add the next time you add a product. I updated the code to check for that.. seems to work but again, haven't tested it widely.

Comment: Yes I test it same way. But I found that subtotal value is zero

Comment: Did you try the code I edited the post?

Comment: Yes, Its due to in my case getPrice() is blank

Comment: odd, it retrieves price everytime for me. Try replacing the line with this instead: $quoteRowTotals[] = $quoteItem['row_total_incl_tax'];

Comment: Hi .. Little late to reply,But this solution work perfectly.